# Understanding of c++ memory order，am I wrong?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<bool> x = false, y = false, go = false;
int v = 0;

// t1
void write_xy() {
  while (!go) {
    std::this_thread::yield();
  }

  v = 1;                                     // 1
  x.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);  // 2
  y.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);  // 3
}

// t2
void read_yx() {
  while (!go) {
    std::this_thread::yield();
  }

  while (!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
    ;

  assert(1 == x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));  // 4
  assert(1 == v);                                  // 5
}

int main() {
  for (;;) {
    x = false;
    y = false;
    v = 0;

    go = false;
    std::thread t1(write_xy);
    std::thread t2(read_yx);
    go = true;  // start
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  }
}
```

As a beginner of C++ concurrent programming, according to my understanding of `memory_order_relaxed`, the execution order of the three statements in the `t1` thread in the above code is not visible to `t2`. From the perspective of `t2`, the three statements in `t1` may have the order of 3, 2, 1, so the assert at 4 and 5 may fire.

After many attempts, `assert` never fired, so I wrote an endless loop repeating the above procedure, and `assert` still didn't fire. Later, it was suspected that `t1` ended before `t2` started execution, so `go` variable was introduced to wait at the beginning of two threads to ensure that both threads started execution as soon as possible, and `assert` was still not triggered.

I test on my virtual machine with Centos8 and 4 CPUs. My CPU is i5-7500.

Comment: AFAIK, x86-64 doesn't have hardware support for `memory_order_relaxed` stores. All stores are release stores. At the assembly level there is no difference between `x.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed)` and `x.store(true, std::memory_order_release)`.

Comment: That something did not happen does not imply that it cannot happen. There are too many parameters that play role here. For instance, IIRC, x64 cannot reorder load-load or store-store operations. Therefore, if they are not reordered by a compiler, it won't happen at runtime. But this does not hold in general for all architectures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just that the language allows for something to happen doesn't mean you'll be able to reproduce it in a given circumstance.

Let's ignore the data race on `v` for now (even though it means your program has Undefined Behavior).

You are compiling the code for x86, which has very strong guarantees about memory ordering built in. For example, you get the exact same assembly code when you perform the stores with `std::memory_order_release`:

https://godbolt.org/z/pZaFDC

```
    mov     DWORD PTR v[rip], 1
    mov     BYTE PTR x[rip], 1
    mov     BYTE PTR y[rip], 1
```

So this code (compiled for your CPU) is guaranteed to have both `v == 1` and `x == 1` visible to all other threads when `y == 1`. Your C++ program did not have this guarantee, but this machine code does.

Similarly, using `std::memory_order_acquire` for the loads has no effect (only the text of the assert message changes):

https://godbolt.org/z/e2-uNA

```
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR y[rip]
[...]
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR x[rip]
[...]
    cmp     DWORD PTR v[rip], 1
```

Again, the platform provides the necessary guarantees already. Other platforms (e.g. ARM) provide fewer guarantees and you would see differences in the compiled binary:

https://godbolt.org/z/Ru4YdD

Here, synchronization is added to all the stores and reads:

```
    bl      __sync_synchronize
```

The above x86 code is also why the data race on `v` has no effect at this moment. *However*, relying on this is a terrible idea, as the compiler would be completely in its rights to e.g. move `assert(v == 1);` before the `while (!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))`. It just currently doesn't happen to do so.

Another way to get the assert would be if the compiler reordered your loads and stores. It would be allowed to do so (whereas with release-acquire ordering as above it would not), but it doesn't, presumably because there's no point in that. You might be able to coax it into doing so by changing the surrounding code, but I can't come up with a way to to do that.

Comment: You might want to add some ARM assembly to contrast x86 with it.

Comment: @Evg Good idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so Is there any way that allows my compiler(gcc) to reorder??

Comment: @honghuibi gcc is allowed to reorder the loads and stores in your original code. It does not reorder them right now. I don't know how to make gcc reorder them.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, not sure if my information is outdated but gcc does little to no optimizations on atomic accesses.